# Please always sort Red status tags to the top of the tag list (Tag tab) in Meta

Tags: feature-request, tags, moderator-tags

Those tags are, to me at least, of higher interest than other tags on this site.

It would be great to be able to see all of them at the top of the list of tags.

Comment: [`*`Cough`*` `*`Cough`*`](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9127/a-script-to-float-system-related-topics-to-the-top-of-the-list-on-mso). (10k+)

Answer (score 1):

I would also put the "required" tag in front of indivual tag lists (on questions)

Answer (score 1):

There are some tags that have a double width border around them, I would put those first. Followed by the <kbd>`status-*`</kbd> tags.

*If you notice the <kbd>`feature-request`</kbd> tag has a double width border, it also happens to be the highest used tag.*