# Tag description/list for "special" tags used on Meta

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, tags, glossary

Meta is home to some wild tag classes, namely that of the **required** or **moderator only** breeds.

These convey a special meaning and run with the winds of each question posted, heralding at quick glance their subject matter or Meta-specific content.

Much like how the [badges page](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/badges) educatifies your mind to what each is for, it would be nice to have a list with a rapid-fire explanation of each of these elevated tags.

Comment: I had a request yesterday to sort all of those tags to the top of the list in the 'Tags' tab.

Comment: This one you mean ? http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6377/please-always-sort-red-status-tags-to-the-top-of-the-tag-list-tag-tab-in-meta

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1195/allow-a-per-tag-home-faq-page

Comment: @Brad: nice one :-)

Comment: I guess this is a duplicate of http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/16681/show-required-tags-when-asking-a-question-on-meta

Answer (score 7, accepted):

### Required - Dark grey borders

[discussion](/questions/tagged/discussion)
Jibber jabber rabble rousing with the other users. Ideas, takes and things that fly out of the top of your skull. About user behaviour, thoughts on the voting system or other such relevant matters.

[feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request)
Wishes and wants for how the trilogy should or could work.

[support](/questions/tagged/support)
How do you work this thing? Or how do you better work with the sites?

[bug](/questions/tagged/bug)
Something's broken with the trilogy. Or something is not working as expected.

### Moderator only - Red

[status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)

The feature requested has been completed or filed as done. Or the bug has been fixed.

[status-bydesign](/questions/tagged/status-bydesign)

This is expected and how the site works. That is all.

[status-declined](/questions/tagged/status-declined)

No. The feature requested or change is not going to happen.

[status-norepro](/questions/tagged/status-norepro)

Unable to replicate the specific bug report.

[status-deferred](/questions/tagged/status-deferred)

This problem lies outside the Stack Overflow code base or with a third party.

[status-planned](/questions/tagged/status-planned)

Got it in the pipeline. Who knows when it'll be out though.

[status-review](/questions/tagged/status-review)

They're looking into it.

[status-reproduced](/questions/tagged/status-reproduced)

Bug report has been successfully replicated.

[faq](/questions/tagged/faq)

Questions and answers covering the basic uses of the site

[featured](/questions/tagged/featured)

Something that's important (right now) for the entire community, and it's show in widgets on the main site(s).

Comment: +1 *"jibber jabber"* makes me think of Mr. T.  _*pities the foo'*_

Comment: @random I added the FAQ tag us normals aren't allowed to use

Comment: Note that this answer duplicates content found at https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/47640/136378 .  However, this answer is out-dated, missing tags like `community-ads` and `featured`.

Answer (score 1):

I added a small **Legend** to the bottom of the /tags page

[image]

The name of the tag gives a hint, and mousing over gives a fuller explanation in the tooltip.