# Show required tags when asking a question on Meta

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, questions, required-tags

On **Meta** we need to add one of the required tags (**[support]**, **[bug]**, **[feature-request]** or **[discussion]**).

I realized that I didn't remember the exact wording of **[support]**, so I had to submit and get the **you are *wrong*** message.

I believe that Stack Exchange will have this feature (required tags), but the required tags should be listed upfront to avoid a failed submit.

<sub>(Will try adding two required tags to see what happens too.)</sub>

Comment: duplicate? http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/25498/error-message-for-moderator-reserved-tags-missing-additional-information-closed

Comment: @warren: no dupe. This question is about required tags every asker has to set on a Meta-question. Your linked ones are about moderator only tags.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

OK, this is complete.

[image]