# Meta Submission Form Should Disclose Tag Requirement

Tags: feature-request, tags, usability, warning

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Show required tags when asking a question on Meta](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/16681/show-required-tags-when-asking-a-question-on-meta)

It's really annoying that the submission form on Meta throws an error when you use it, informing you that one of various tags must be included (unless you psychically know ahead of time and use one). The mandatory tags should be listed up front.