# Validate input BEFORE running captcha - not after

Tags: bug, status-norepro, captcha

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Show required tags when asking a question on Meta](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/16681/show-required-tags-when-asking-a-question-on-meta)

Steps to reproduce:

- Formulate a question
- Insert a few valid tags, but not one of the required ones
- Click "Post Your Question"

Excepted results:

- Site reminds you to add one of the required tags (bug, feature-request, discussion, etc.)

Actual results:

- Site expects you to solve a CAPTCHA, and only *then* tells you to add one of the required tags, then expects you to solve *another* CAPTCHA

Comment: Do you get a CAPTCHA every time you post?

Comment: Maybe a duplicate, but I get this too, all the time.

Answer (score 1):

The 2nd captcha is currently not very desirable, but by-design.

I can't repro getting the captcha on the 1st attempt though.