# Could the meta tagging help include the mandatory tags?

Tags: feature-request, tags

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Show required tags when asking a question on Meta](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/16681/show-required-tags-when-asking-a-question-on-meta)

There are a few mandatory tags on meta: *bug, feature-request, discussion,* and *support.* This is pointed out when you try to ask the question without one of them imcluded. However, I think it'd be helpful if that also appears in the tagging help box on the right.

Comment: Sorry, feature requests that make sense are not acceptable on Meta Stackoverflow. The only requests that are valid are ones that include unicorns, waffles, or some other random item.

Comment: Ah, the joys of synonyms. Didn't show up to me in the list of possibly related questions. This is getting sorta like the Mozilla bugtracker—submit right away since others will close the issue as dupe faster than you could search for one ;-)

Comment: It's fun that the viewers divide in close-voters and up-voters—the latter shouldn't be, given that there is a dupe.