# Why are some tags colored/formatted differently in meta.stackoverflow.com?

Tags: discussion, tags, design, meta

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Tag description/list for “special” tags used on Meta](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6476/tag-description-list-for-special-tags-used-on-meta)

Some tags are colored in red:

- faq
- status-bydesign
- status-completed
- status-deferred
- status-declined
- status-planned
- stauts-norepro
- status-reproduced
- status-review

While others have a dark gray border:

- bug
- discussion
- feature-request
- support

I couldn't find any information about this in the [FAQ](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/faq), nor a [Google search](http://www.google.com/search?hl=en&q=site:meta.stackoverflow.com+why+are+some+tags+colored) on meta.stackoverflow.com.

I was wondering if there is a comprehensive explanation as to the differences between these tags and the other (normally colored) tags. (If there isn't one, I guess this answer could be the resource to describe it to other users.)

Comment: Should the title be "What are the special tags in meta.stackoverflow.com?" or "Why are some tags colored/formatted differently in meta.stackoverflow.com?"? I think both are valid titles, and both are equally likely to be searched for (e.g. in Google). Should there be two questions with one of them linking to the other?

Comment: Also a duplicate of http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/47634/how-are-the-rules-different-on-meta

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Moderator Tags (red colored tags)

These tags can only be used by moderators. If you try submitting a question with one of these, you will see an error message similar to the following:

> the tag 'faq' is moderator-only

Their meanings are as follows:

- **faq**: a frequently asked question, as determined by the moderators. If you believe that your question should be tagged with *faq*, you could tag it with the non-moderator tag *faq-proposed* instead.
- **status-bydesign**: the bug reported is in fact not a bug, it is the intended behavior.
- **status-completed**: the bug has been fixed or the feature has been implemented.
- **status-deferred**:
- **status-declined**: a feature request was declined by the development team and won't be implemented.
- **status-planned**: a bug or feature request will be implemented in the near future.
- **status-norepro**: the bug was not reproducible by the development team.
- **status-reproduced**: the bug was reproduced by the development team, a fix is likely to occur in the near future.
- **status-review**:

---

### Other Tags (dark gray border tags)

Your question must have at least one of these tags specified, otherwise you will see the error message:

> must include one of these tags -- bug feature-request discussion support

Their meanings are as follows:

- **bug**: a bug on one of the stackoverflow trilogy sites was found and submitted. It may then be tagged by one of the following: status-norepro, status-reproduced, status-completed, or status-bydesign.
- **feature-request**: a change to the trilogy has been requested by a user. It may then be tagged by one of the following: status-deferred, status-completed, status-declined, status-planned, or status-review.
- **support**:
- **discussion**:

Comment: I made this answer a wiki, feel free to improve it.