# Special meaning for tag color

Tags: support, tags

Is there any special meaning of different color's of tag ? I search in meta but unable to find any thing about this.May I missing some thing to understand?

For example:

> > [image: tag color]

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/47640/209357

Comment: @Oded [this one](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/48315/152859) is better fitting as dupe. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The highlighted tags are those that only moderators and developers can set.

For example - [status-bydesign](/questions/tagged/status-bydesign) is not something regular users can set.