# The Tags page should provide easy access to the special tag list

Tags: feature-request, tags

Currently, meta users can see a list of special tags in several ways:

Via [How does Meta Stack Exchange work - Required Tags](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/47640/136378)
Via [Tag description/list for "special" tags used on Meta](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/37424/136378) (not up to date)
Via https://meta.stackexchange.com/tags  (by manually paging through the list).

I propose this be made a bit easier, using one of two solutions:

The Elegant Solution:
Provide filters on https://meta.stackexchange.com/tags for both moderator tags and required tags.  These could be hidden in the legend section at the bottom of that page or added as additional filters in the Popular/Name/New filter bar in the top right of the page.

The Easy solution:
Add a link pointing to [How does Meta Stack Exchange work - Required Tags](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/47640/136378)  to the legend section of https://meta.stackexchange.com/tags

The elegant solution is self-maintaining, but the benefits of that approach may be too minor to justify the cost.